# is there any cause for concern using log4net with .NET 3.5 and later

Tags: logging, log4net

I have read this [page](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/framework-support.html) and noticed that .NET 3.5 is not specifically listed.  Is this cause for concern?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, .NET 3.5 uses the same CLR version as .NET 2.0, so absolutely no cause for concern.

Answer (score 0):

No worries at all.  I'm using log4net in several 3.5 applications.